# Can a toilet be properly installed without a flange?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, installation

Someone put a toilet in for me, he used different bolts than came with the toilet because he said the bolts that came with the toilet wouldn't work. He said the floor was rotting but he needed to get under the house and toilet to see what to do about it at a later date.

He also didn't use the wax ring that came with the toilet, instead putting two standard wax rings under toilet for a better seal, he said. He later told me that there was no flange under the old toilet either.

What do I do now?

Comment: "the floor was rotting" & "no flange under the old toilet" - seeing the connection here? I hope he comes back soon or you'll be seeing what's under your floor for yourself while sitting in a somewhat compromising position ...

Comment: The floor is rotting and you're not going to fix that?  Just asking for trouble, regardless of the quality of the new toilet installation.

Answer (score 3):

The flange and accompanying bolts hold the toilet firmly to the floor and keeps the seal between the toilet and the floor.

Without the flange or if it is broken, he would have to attach the toilet to the subfloor with wood screws, and if the floor is rotting out, those won't last long.

Sounds like it will need further repairs sometime soon.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like he's telling you flat out, and in no uncertain terms, that this is a temporary hack.

He is telling you the floor under the toilet has some serious problems.  He is saying no one can fix the toilet properly without those floor repairs getting done.

Using two wax rings is perfectly fine.  He probably used two that fit well together.  They also make double-height wax rings for that purpose.

He's not the bad guy here.  It's the rotten floor.

What commonly causes a floor to rot is a leak that is not promptly fixed.  Another source of moisture under toilets is condensation on the outside of the tank which runs down to the floor.